# Backpressure in storm

Tags: apache-storm

In our storm 1.0.2 application  we are facing out of memory exceptions.Upon debugging we saw that the Kafka spout was emitting too many messages to the bolts . The bolts were running at a capacity of almost 4.0. So is there a way to enable backpressure in storm so that the spout emits depending on the capacity in bolts. Tried enabling the topology.backpressure.enable to true but ran to this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1949. We are using the out of the box implementation of KafkaSpout and extending the BaseRichBolt for our bolts .Our DAG is linear.

Answer (score 7):

You can handle the back pressure of the KafkaSpout by setting the **maxSpoutPending** value in the topology configuration,

```
Config config = new Config();
config.setMaxSpoutPending(200); 
config.setMessageTimeoutSecs(100);

StormSubmitter.submitTopology("testtopology", config, builder.createTopology());
```

maxSpoutPending is the number of tuples that can be pending acknowledgement in your topology at a given time. Setting this property, will intimate the KafkaSpout not to consume any more data from Kafka unless the unacknowledged tuple count is less than maxSpoutPending value.

Answer (score 2):

look at this comment:

/**
* Specifies whether the spout should require Storm to track emitted tuples when using a {@link ProcessingGuarantee} other than
* {@link ProcessingGuarantee#AT_LEAST_ONCE}. The spout will always track emitted tuples when offering at-least-once guarantees
* regardless of this setting. This setting is false by default.
*
*

Enabling tracking can be useful even in cases where reliability is not a concern, because it allows
* {@link Config#TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING} to have an effect, and enables some spout metrics (e.g. complete-latency) that would
* otherwise be disabled.
*
* @param tupleTrackingEnforced true if Storm should track emitted tuples, false otherwise
*/

---

I think one of these two configs can help:

components:

- id: "spoutConfigBuilder"

  className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpoutConfig$Builder"
  constructorArgs:

  - ${ENV-KAFKA_ADDRESS}
  - [${ENV-KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME}]

  properties:

  - name : "processingGuarantee"
    value: AT_LEAST_ONCE ***(1)***
  - name: "tupleTrackingEnforced"
    value: true ***(2)***